# EPiServer call to clientside script from c# using ScriptManager

Tags: c#, javascript, client-side, scriptmanager, episerver

When working with EPiServer calling a client-side function requires a specific syntax due the way EPiServer takes over the ScriptManager.

If you are writing code behind for an EPiServer project use this:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction()", true);
```

Where 'myFunction' is the name of you client-side function.

**Also:** Remember that you function will need to be defined where it can be picked up by the server-side code, so I'd recommend putting it in the global namespace.

Comment: Is this a question? :)

Comment: No, it's just useful code, but wasn't sure where else to put it in order to help people.

Comment: Ok! :) There is a section on EPiServer World if you want to post useful code snippets: http://world.episerver.com/Code/

Cheers!